# Configuration system failed to initialize [After Login]

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to Visual Studio and working on a assignment project.

I have this code:

```
Global.System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(Global.System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString), _
         Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\UsersPasswords.mdb")> _
        Public ReadOnly Property UsersPasswordsConnectionString() As String
            **Get
                Return CType(Me("UsersPasswordsConnectionString"), String)
            End Get**
        End Property
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**Keep getting this error.** Explain if you can thanks. The problem persistent around the BOLD coding highlighted above.! This message follows the coding --> *Live event: Exception Intercepted: An exception was intercepted & the call stack unwound to the point before the call from the user code where the exception occurred."Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" is selected in the debugger options.*

Comment: It is not an error, just a notification.  A side-effect of writing little test projects that have the same name.  You are loading a user.config file of an old project.  Nothing actually goes wrong, it will disappear once you actually change a setting so the file gets rewritten.

Comment: Are you sure? also how do I change the setting so the file gets rewritten?

Comment: Alright so for some reason I messed around with the settings and enter Check | Boolean | User and it worked, anyway problem solved, but can someone tell me the reason why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so for some reason I messed around with the settings and enter Check | Boolean | User and it worked, anyway problem solved, but can someone tell me the reason why this happened?

Thanks.